# Mac-like search bar in task bar

Tags: unity, python, search

I like the Unity Dash and all, but it can take a while to load (older computer with 1GB RAM).

So I was wondering if it would be possible to create a program in Python that puts a search bar (like on Macs) up in the area as the notification icons so I could quickly search.

Is this possible, or would it be an absurd amount of work for a little program like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out that there is, in fact, something like this. I saw it on the OMG! Ubuntu site, and here is the link: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/09/spotlight-like-tool-coming-to-pear-os-other-distros

**NOTE:** This program is still in development, so it isn't fully stable yet and

> **Quote:** (from article): Indicator-Search is currently in development so only install it if you’re okay with bugs, crashes and unexpected behaviour.

Sadly, there, so far, isn't a keyboard shortcut like on mac (no <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open Spotlight) though I'm sure there is a work-around.